# How to determine the Standard Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this question below:

The linear Transformation R: R3 → R3 is rotation around the vector [1 1 1] T
with angle [image] according to the right-hand rule

Determine the standard matrix A to R. Indicate the matrix [image].

I think that i should use the identity matrix but i am totally lost?
What do they mean with indicate the matrix?

Comment: What did you try ?  You should show some effort in solving the problem in the statement of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of the  [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)? Let $k=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$ in the formula and
$$
K=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then,
$$
\begin{align}
R&=I+(\sin\frac{2\pi}{3})K+(1-\cos\frac{2\pi}{3})K^2\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array}\right).
\end{align}
$$

You should check what $R$ does to $(1,1,1)^T$ and vectors orthogonal to this vector. Also, when taking $R^6$, remember that this rotates by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ six times. Without doing the matrix calculation, what should you get? What about $R^3$?

Comment: Thanks i haven't heard about that how does it works?

Comment: The Wikipedia page does a good job of explaining the derivation I think. The original statement is in vector notation and deals with rotating a vector $\mathbf{v}$ about a unit vector $\mathbf{k}$ by angle $\theta$. The idea is to decompose $\mathbf{v}$ into two parts: a component parallel to $\mathbf{k}$ and a component perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$, where the parallel component stays the same under rotation but the perpendicular component is rotated. Adding these components together, you get the rotated vector.

Comment: By the way, the matrix $R$ that we get is particularly simple. Note that it permutes the $x,y,z$ axes. A geometric way to see this without the formula is to imagine you are looking along the vector $(1,1,1)$ at the axes intersecting at the origin. If you rotate by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ in that perspective, each axis just gets rotated to its neighbor.

Comment: How do i plug in the degree and the vector to get the matrix?